How to use Regex to find letter which following by <=AAA in Python?
I have the following code
def append_letter():
  string = 'ACAABAACAAABACDBADDDFSDDDFFSSSASDAFAAACBAAAFASD'

  result = []
  # compete the pattern below
  pattern = r'(?<=AAA)\w+'
  for item in re.finditer(pattern, string):
    # identify the group number below.
    result.append(item.group(1))
  return result

How to append the letter not included A letter
from script above I want to append any letter follow by triple A included A to a list.
How to achieve this by modifies only this line of code:
pattern = r'(?<=AAA)\w+'


You could use re.findall with a positive lookahead.
>>> import re
>>> str = 'ACAABAACAAABACDBADDDFSDDDFFSSSASDAFAAACBAAAFASD'
>>> re.findall(r'.(?=AAA)', str)
['C', 'F', 'B']

Or if you must use re.finditer:
>>> [match[0] for match in re.finditer(r'.(?=AAA)', str)]
['C', 'F', 'B']

I don't think it's crazy to prefer the directness of the former.
Either way the correct pattern to match any character followed by AAA is:
r'.(?=AAA)'


try this:
import re

def append_letter():
    string = 'ACAABAACAAABACDBADDDFSDDDFFSSSASDAFAAACBAAAFASD'

    result = []
    # Complete the pattern below
    pattern = r'(?<=AAA)\w'
    for item in re.finditer(pattern, string):
        result.append(item.group())
    return result

# Call the function and store the result
letters_following_AAA = append_letter()

# Print the result
print(letters_following_AAA)

the code outputs ["B", "C", "F"]

We don't want to add more script out of original code.

I don't understand, do you mean you want the code to be shorter?

As I mention, I want to modifies only on pattern line, just modify here r'(?<=AAA)\w'
to append result as list we have, C,B,D, ...

if I'm understanding correctly, try this: r'(?<=AAA)[^A]\w+'
